# Cell data from table column Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a table, I want to retrieve the cells inner HTML from column two.

```
<table id="myTable" border="1">

<tbody>

    <tr>

        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>

    </tr>

</tbody>
```

In this example I would like to return the three 'B' cells in column two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markup:

```
<table id="myTable">
<tbody>
<tr>

    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>

</tr>

<tr>

    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>

</tr>

<tr>

    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
var cellData = [];
var i;

var myTable = document.querySelector('#myTable');

for (i=0; i<myTable.rows.length; i++) {
  cellData.push(myTable.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML);
}

console.log(cellData);
```

Comment: Thank you! I almost had it, was missing .push